# Set filename when exporting report via URL

Tags: reporting

One of my favorite Salesforce reports tricks is that you can automatically download a report by adding URL parameters to the URL.

A link like this will immediately download the indicated report in CSV format:

> https://domain.my.salesforce.com/00OA000000xxxxx?**export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv**

Is there a way to control what the default filename of the downloaded report will be?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could control the filename via a query string parameter. It seems like it would be open to abuse.

Comment: One hack idea, pull the report down as a blob in apex and then save it as an attachment with the required name. Then use `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=` + the attachment Id to download the attachment instead.

Comment: Cool idea, MUCH more complicated than I need :)